# A do-until algorithm that enters two hundred elements in a array

Tags: java

This is a question in basic principles of programing . I find it difficult to write a algorithm that enters two hundred elements into an array

Comment: What have you attempted? What kind of array and what are the elements?

Comment: Thabang do you want to fill an array ? like read numbers from user and put those into an array ?

Comment: I attempted the do until loop but i get confused when it says that the algorithm must enter the two hundred unknown.I know There's is two hundred unknown elements. The array name is someThings

Comment: do you want to rewrite a for loop into a do-until loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the array is called `someThings` and initialized to hold 200 things, like so... `int[]someThings = new int[200];`

Let's take a look at [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) which we will use to generate random numbers.

Random rand = new Random();

You may use a for-loop like so...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
    someThings[i] = rand.nextInt();
```

Alternatively, this is how a do-while loop could look.

```
int index = 0;
do {
    someThings[index] = rand.nextInt();
    index++;
} while(index < 200)
```

The idea being:

1. Create an array (size 200)
2. Write a loop going from 0 to 199, and insert some value into each index of the array.